# INSERT and then UPDATE in the same stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on this stored procedure that needs to 1st insert the row and then update the row. The issue I am having is grabbing the id of the initially inserted row so that I can later update the correct row.

Currently, this requires my Visual Studio program to have @searchID to be defined in my program. However, I just want the row id to be "local" to the stored procedure, not ever interacting with my program in Visual Studio. Is there a way to create a local variable in stored procedure perhaps that doesn't touch my c# code in visual studio?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsFormRegistrant]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @EventId int,
     @FormId int,
     @ColumnName varchar(100),
     @ColumnValue varchar(100),
     @searchID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 -- Insert statements for procedure here


 IF  @searchID = null
 BEGIN

declare @Query nvarchar(4000)
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)

    set @Query = 'INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ 
             (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)'
    set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int'
    exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID

    SET @searchID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
ELSE
declare @Query2 nvarchar(4000)
declare @ParmDefinition2 nvarchar(500)

    set @Query2 = 'UPDATE Registrant SET DateCreated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, EventId = @EventId, FormId = @FormId, @ColumnName = @ColumnName, @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue WHERE RegistrantId = @searchID'
    set @ParmDefinition2 = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int, @searchID int'
    exec sp_executesql @Query2, @ParmDefinition2, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID,
                   @searchID = @searchID

 END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you cannot check `NULL` with `=` operator use `IS` unless you made initial setting change. so it should be

```
 IF  @searchID IS null
```

To get the last inserted identity value add the `set @searchID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` inside dynamic query and get the result through output parameter.

```
set @Query = 'INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ 
             (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)

set @searchID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'

    set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int,@searchID  INT OUTPUT'
    exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID,
                   @searchID = @searchID OUTPUT;
```

**Update query:**

```
   set @Query2 = 'UPDATE Registrant SET DateCreated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, EventId = @EventId, FormId = @FormId, ' +quotename(@ColumnName)+ ' =  @ColumnValue WHERE RegistrantId = @searchID'
    set @ParmDefinition2 = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int, @searchID int'
    exec sp_executesql @Query2, @ParmDefinition2, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID,
                   @searchID = @searchID
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Okay so I am getting a compile error for `@searchID OUTPUT;` as it says it must be in this format: `@searchID = OUTPUT;` . So I tried this, and my program still asks for @searchID. I think the syntax is not quite right for this part?

Comment: @MusicBackup - can you post the error that you got when you executed my query

Comment: Sure. At the line that has `@searchID OUTPUT;` ... Must pass parameter number 6 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.

Comment: @MusicBackup - Check now

Comment: Thanks, that removed the compile error. Now my program in Visual Studio still asks for @searchID though... I am wondering how to eliminate that.

Comment: Not sure why visual studio ask for it. but now `@searchID` should be available in update query. Did you check that

Comment: Yes. It inserts into my table but brings up this error:  Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@ColumnName".

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to having `INSERT` and `UPDATE` as separate queries is to use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). The query should be similar to the one below (consider it a pseudo-code):

```
MERGE Registrant AS target
USING (
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue
)
ON (RegistrantId = @searchID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET EventId = @EventId, FormId = @FormId ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ 
             (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)
    (DateCreated,EventId,FormId, @ColumnName)
    VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)
```

MERGE has the advantage that it executes atomically (everything succeeds or fails) and you can also use it for batch operations (`INSERT` or `UPDATE` for multiple searched identifiers at once)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this existed. I will try this out.